# Joining tables on A or B or C

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table:

```
docname, specialtycode1, specialtycode2, specialtycode3
```

i have another table

```
    specialtycode1, specialtycode1desc
specialtycode2, specialtrycode2desc
specialtycode3, specialtycode3desc
```

the result that i want is:

```
docname, specialtycode1, secialtycode1desc, 
  specialtycode2, specialtycode2desc, 
  specialtycode3, specialtycode3desc
```

i tried to do a query like this:

```
join dbo.SpecialtyMapping as f on (e.specialtycode1=f.specialtyabbrev
                                or e.specialtycode2=f.specialtyabbrev
                                or e.specialtycode3=f.specialtyabbrev)
```

i dont think this is the right solution but do not know where to start. please help!

here is the full query:

```
WITH cte(rejected) AS (SELECT DISTINCT [Specimen ID]
                                                 FROM         dbo.QuickLabDump
                                                 WHERE     (Outcome = 'REJECTED') AND ([Specimen ID] IS NOT NULL))
    SELECT     CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.[Date Entered], 1) AS [Full Date], DATEPART(yy, a.[Date Entered]) AS [Year Entered], LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, a.[Date Entered]), 3) 
                            AS [Month Entered], DATEPART(dd, a.[Date Entered]) AS [Day Entered], CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) 
                            = 1 THEN 'Sun' WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) = 2 THEN 'Mon' WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) 
                            = 3 THEN 'Tus' WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) = 4 THEN 'Wed' WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) 
                            = 5 THEN 'Thu' WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) = 6 THEN 'Fri' WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE entered]) = 7 THEN 'Sat' END AS DOW, 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(D, - (1 * DATEPART(dw, a.[Date Entered])) + 6, a.[Date Entered]), 1) AS [Week Ending], COUNT(DISTINCT a.[Specimen ID]) 
                            AS CountAccns, c.SALESREP AS [Sales Rep], c.NPI AS MLNPI, e.NPIb AS IMSNPI, e.SpecialtyPrimaryCodeb AS [IMS Specialty Primary Code],
                            f.specialtydesc,
                            e.SpecialtySecondaryCodeb AS [IMS Specialty Secondary Code], e.SpecialtyTertiaryCodeb AS [IMS Specialty Tertiary Code], 
                            e.ProfessionalID1b AS [IMS Professional ID 1], a.[Requesting Physician] AS Physician, a.[Practice Code], b.[MLIS Practice ID] AS [MLIS Code], a.[Practice Name], 
                            c.DATEESTABLISHED AS [Date Established], c.PRACTICEADDRESS1 AS Address, c.PRACTICEADDRESS2 AS Address2, c.PRACTICECITY AS City, 
                            c.PRACTICESTATE AS State, d.[MLIS Status] AS Status, MAX(a.[Order Count]) AS [order count]
     FROM         dbo.QuickLabDump AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            dbo.qlmlismapping AS b ON b.[Quicklab ID] = a.[Practice Code] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            dbo.PracticeandPhysician AS c ON a.[Requesting Physician] = c.DOCTORFIRSTNAME + ' ' + c.DOCTORLASTNAME AND 
                            a.[Practice Code] = c.PRACTICECODE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            dbo.IMSData AS e ON c.NPI = e.NPIb LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            dbo.QLMLISInfo AS d ON b.[MLIS Practice ID] = d.[MLIS Practice ID]
                            join dbo.SpecialtyMapping as f on (e.specialtyprimarycodeb=f.specialtyabbrev
                                or e.specialtysecondarycodeb=f.specialtyabbrev
                                or e.specialtytertiarycodeb=f.specialtyabbrev)
     WHERE     (a.[Date Entered] > '20110101') AND (NOT EXISTS
                                (SELECT     1 AS Expr1
                                  FROM          cte AS cte_1
                                  WHERE      (rejected = a.[Specimen ID]))) AND (NOT EXISTS
                                (SELECT     1 AS Expr1
                                  FROM          dbo.PendingSpecimens
                                  WHERE      ([Specimen ID] = a.[Specimen ID])))
     GROUP BY a.[Date Entered], c.SALESREP, c.NPI, e.NPIb, e.SpecialtyPrimaryCodeb, e.SpecialtySecondaryCodeb, e.SpecialtyTertiaryCodeb, e.ProfessionalID1b, 
                            a.[Requesting Physician], a.[Practice Code], b.[MLIS Practice ID], a.[Practice Name], c.DATEESTABLISHED, c.PRACTICEADDRESS1, c.PRACTICEADDRESS2, 
                            c.PRACTICECITY, c.PRACTICESTATE, d.[MLIS Status],f.specialtydesc
```

Comment: Did it produce an error?  And what is the full query (you haven't posted the SELECT, FROM or the other table)

Comment: @SirCrispalot no error but it has been going for like 20min and still no results

Comment: Could you include the names of the tables and your full query please?

Comment: How do you look at that code without getting vertigo?

Comment: Now you know why it is better to use proper normalization than to have 'specialtycode1', 'specialtycode2', 'specialtycode3' in a single table.

Comment: Ugh and the meaningless aliases... `a,b,c,d,e,f...` alphabet soup.

Answer (score 1):

If you have three "specialty codes" as columns in your first table, you will either need three JOINs, or you could unpivot the data from your docName table and do a single JOIN. I'll run with the solution that won't require too much modification of your original query:

```
SELECT
    ims.docname
    ,ims.specialtycode1, sm1.specialtycode1desc
    ,ims.specialtycode2, sm2.specialtycode2desc
    ,ims.specialtycode3, sm3.specialtycode3desc
FROM
    dbo.IMSData ims
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.SpecialtyMapping sm1 ON ims.specialtycode1 = sm1.specialtyabbrev
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.SpecialtyMapping sm2 ON ims.specialtycode2 = sm2.specialtyabbrev
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.SpecialtyMapping sm3 ON ims.specialtycode3 = sm3.specialtyabbrev
```

As long as your `SpecialtyMapping` table's rows are unique, this should work.

**EDIT** - Updated to `LEFT JOIN`s as per suggestions in the comments. I also noticed that the column names don't quite exactly match the ones you have in your query, but you'll get the gist.

Comment: @I__: I have no idea if it will speed anything up; that's a pretty good-sized query and the problem with your performance could be somewhere else.

Comment: Probably what you need are left joins. That aside, I think this is the solution.

Comment: I was going to also suggest left joins since we don't know whether the three code columns in the main table are nullable.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a lot that could go into a long running query.

Where to start looking.

1. How much data? If you have masses and masses of data your query much always take long no matter how good your query. However most databases can take pretty huge amounts in their stride so lets assume that is not an issue.
2. Are you tables index on the columns you are joining? The database need to find the columns that you are joining on, if they are not indexed this process could take really long, index the columns you are joining on something like

   create clustered index IX_Your_IndexName on Your_TableName (Column1, Column2, etc)
3. Learn how to read the execution plan, this will actually tell you why your query is running slow. Great place to start! [Here is an article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/see-sql-server-graphical-execution-plans-in-action/198) to get you started.

Good luck.